# how to can I read from ELM327?

Tags: vb.net-2010

I'm working now on ELM327 software which help me to make scan for cars.
but now i'm in the begging , so how could i make My software read from ELM327, also is there's any source code can help me in my project?

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you are using bluetooth or a USB.Usually if you buy an elm 327 device you get the Software to read it. If you want your own software to read it then you have to send AT commands to it, to get responses

Comment: sir,I'm working with cable one.. but I think there's library to allow the connection same as that one for dealing with scanner